# Navigation Error in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

[image: I want to navigate from left controller to right controller by clicking the "here" button]

[image: Here is the code for Sign In button navigation and also the "here" button to navigate to the right controller]

The "here" button navigate to the next controller is having the segue name "gotoSignUp", but in the program, I've clicked the "here" button and the error existed. Is my code having some problem to make the navigation? The Segue name "gotoLogin" no problem at all, but "gotoSignUp" have error after I clicked the "here" button.
[image: The error is shown like this]

[image: This is the error as I can't print screen whole error output]

Comment: What is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: Which error existed?

Comment: Something has already invoked the segue when shouldPerformSegue is called, so you should not be calling performSegue inside shouldPerformSegue. Delete that line, and see if that fixes the error

Comment: @pasta12 I will post the error here as picture, i edit the post again now, but i print screen it partially since the error is so long

Comment: You left out the actual error...

Comment: @FabioRitrovato okay, top error I print screen again, sorry for that :)

Comment: @FabioRitrovato done edited, you can take a look now

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manually perform the segue, it's already happening on it's own.

The delegate asks you if the segue with that identifier should happen, so if it's "gotoSignUp", just return true to make it continue

Comment: This is doesn't work since I've tried it just now, I also thought that return true is the way to solve it out, but it didn't.

Comment: I feel there was no need to down vote our answers, since they might not be the actual solution (they could have since the limited info at the time), but also, they are not wrong, you still should not perform the segue manually

Comment: I'm not the one who down vote you, I've already vote you up to make this comment to 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue, it is an xcode 6 bug with ios 8. Apple still haven't fixed this problem until now, I just disabled the auto layout in the right hand side controller then it can be navigated now.

Answer (score -1):

Inside `shouldPerformSegue` you only need to return `true` or `false`. You should never call `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside this method

```
if idintifier == "gotoSignUp"
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: Yup, I wrote like this and didn't work as well